# find and replace a value in a line of text

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, replace

I have a text file which contain only 1 line of text

```
1314:Battery:1.90:50:30
```

I'm trying to figure out if is there anyway to do a `grep` and `sed` to change the value 50 and 30 to the following

```
1314:Battery:1.90:45:35
```

which I would reduce 5 from 50 and increase 5 from 30.

Please guide me if there is a better way to solve this problem ? I just started picking up this scripting. Thanks =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -i -F: -lape '$F[3]-=5;$F[4]+=5;$_=join ":",@F' the-file
```

With `sh` (assuming those numbers are always decimal integers without leading zeros):

```
IFS=: read -r a b c d e < the-file &&
  printf '%s\n' "$a:$b:$c:$((d-5)):$((e+5))" > the-file
```

With recent versions of GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -F: -vOFS=: '{$4-=5;$5+=5}1' the-file
```

**Do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -F":" '{OFS=":"; print $1,$2,$3,$4-5,$5+5}' filename
```

Output:

```
1314:Battery:1.90:45:35
```

Comment: This works good.  You could also use `printf` with the format if you do not want to use `OFS`.